# How to push Angular4 app to cloudfoundary

Tags: angular, cloud-foundry

I am new to Cloudfoundary. Created application using angular4 and try to push this code cloudfoundary but am getting below error

```
2018-03-30T16:13:44.22+0530 [HEALTH/0] ERR Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused
```

2018-03-30T16:13:44.22+0530 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.

created manifest file like below

```
applications:
- name: angular-xxx
  command: ng serve
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
```

Pushed the code using below command

```
**cf push**
```

When run this one, every thing is creating like route, app name and building angular app also.

- 2018-03-30T16:22:31.43+0530 [API/5] OUT Process has crashed with
     type: "web"

  ```
    2018-03-30T16:22:33.34+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 2c755-871c-7b1e603
  ```

  successfully destroyed container for instance e3817-8594
     2018-03-30T16:30:39.38+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 2c755-871c-7b1e603
     creating container for instance a718ea-774b-6254
     2018-03-30T16:30:39.90+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 2c755-871c-7b1e603
     successfully created container for instance a718ea-774b-6254
     2018-03-30T16:30:44.89+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring
     of container    2018-03-30T16:30:48.20+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT **
     NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your
     browser on http://localhost:4200/ **    2018-03-30T16:30:59.92+0530
     [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Date: 2018-03-30T11:00:59.920Z
     2018-03-30T16:30:59.92+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Hash: 5157599999834 
     2018-03-30T16:30:59.92+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Time: 11661ms
     2018-03-30T16:30:59.92+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT chunk {inline}
     inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
     2018-03-30T16:30:59.92+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT chunk {main}
     main.bundle.js (main) 63.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
     2018-03-30T16:30:59.92+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT chunk {polyfills}
     polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 549 kB [initial] [rendered]
     2018-03-30T16:30:59.92+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT chunk {styles}
     styles.bundle.js (styles) 41.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
     2018-03-30T16:30:59.92+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT chunk {vendor}
     vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 9.5 MB [initial] [rendered]
     2018-03-30T16:30:59.98+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT webpack: Compiled
     successfully.    2018-03-30T16:31:45.15+0530 [HEALTH/0] ERR Failed to
     make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused
     2018-03-30T16:31:45.15+0530 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health
     check never passed.

Please help me on this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: ng serve is a **development** server. Learn how to **build** your angular application for production. This will generate a few static files. Any web server able to serve static files can then be used to serve these static files. Angular executes in the browser. https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 3):

So , There are few steps you need to perform before pushing you app to container.

Build Step:

1. Add `StaticFile` file in base directory
2. copy the following line in StaticFile 
    pushstate: enabled
3. Now open your `angular-cli.json` file and update following content

"assets":[
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "Staticfile"
   ],

4. now you are ready to build you project and deploy. - ng build

Deployment Steps:

1. Add `buildpack: staticfile_buildpack` in your manifest file
2. now you are good to use to cf push

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html

Comment: @RamRajVasavi: Please "Mark as Answer" on the post If it helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.